# Side By Side Arrangement of Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I place the two cards side by side, where they are of equal width and adjust accordingly with the width of the screen?

I tried wrapping the cards in a separate div and adding `display: flex;` property; however, it makes the cards small and doesn't make them fit the width of the screen.

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <style>
        .custom-box {
            background-color: #ff5733;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .box-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .box-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .custom-button {
            background-color: #ff8f33;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .custom-button:hover {
            background-color: #ff5722;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            margin: 10px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-box">
        <div class="box-title">Dropdown Menu</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <button class="custom-button" id="dropdown-button">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 1</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 2</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropdownButton = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');
        const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

        dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            dropdownMenu.style.display = dropdownMenu.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, wrap with flex but also add width: 100% for the children. Also added media query, so font doesn't overflow on small screens.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <style>
        .custom-box {
            background-color: #ff5733;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .box-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .box-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .custom-button {
            background-color: #ff8f33;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .custom-button:hover {
            background-color: #ff5722;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            margin: 10px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-box">
        <div class="box-title">Dropdown Menu</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <button class="custom-button" id="dropdown-button">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 1</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 2</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="custom-box">
        <div class="box-title">Dropdown Menu</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <button class="custom-button" id="dropdown-button">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 1</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 2</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropdownButton = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');
        const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

        dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            dropdownMenu.style.display = dropdownMenu.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The flex: 1 1 auto property on the .card elements tells the browser to give each card equal width, and to grow or shrink the cards as needed to fit the container.